# How to force an application to use a specific network card?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, batch-file

So let's say i have multiple network cards, each of them connected to a different router & ISP.

how can i force an app to use a specific connection? when i enable all the connections in windows 10, all the apps will connected to the first one enabled

is there any software that does this? or maybe a batch file?

I also have a Kaspersky Internet Security but couldn't find such option in it.

Comment: The silmplest way, I see, is to run the application in a virtual machine and to bind his VM  to a specified interface.

Comment: @schweik but i remember someone wrote a batch file for me that did this but I dont remember how, in it we specified the application and the network card(connection), therefore running that batch file would've opened that app with that connection

Comment: Not actually the first one, the one with the highest metric

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip).

You have to run it from the command line, but you could easily wrap that in a batch file if it's something you do often.

As an example, let's assume that your primary network card has an IP address of 192.168.1.10 and the secondary card has an IP of 192.168.254.10.  Normally, all traffic routes out through the primary IP address and therefore out the primary router.  If you wanted to use Chrome to browse out of the other interface, you would do something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ForceBindIP\ForceBindIP64.exe" 192.168.254.10 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can get ForceBindIP to work with Firefox. I even tried various versions of Chrome 7x and ForceBindIP doesn't want to work.

Comment: @Sun They explicitly explain on their page that it does not works with Chrome and what's the reason.

Comment: They state older versions of Chrome may work, but I was not unable to use ForceBindIP on portable versions of Chrome 70 to Chrome 79. I might have used the tools incorrectly, but going back to old versions did not allow me to use Chrome. Firefox it is.

Answer (score 0):

If [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip) doesn't work, I recommend running a proxy on each adapter (I use CCProxy) and using programs like Proxycap (for UDP and TCP packets) or Proxifier (for TCP packets only) to force applications to use that proxy, ensuring they utilize the specified adapter. If you plan to use this setup daily, consider having a static IP for each adapter to avoid resetting configurations after restarting your PC. I've created a video about it, you can find the link [here](https://youtu.be/j6IkutrMCbI?si=5hARPjIuRPuHz7r6)